# How to change dash shell to bash shell in Travis CI

Tags: linux, bash, github, ubuntu-14.04, travis-ci

Hi I was trying to setup a CI for one of my Project. It is based on yocto and is hosted in github. I was planning to use travis as CI tool. Now I am facing a problem with the shell in  the travis server. yocto requires bash shell but VM in  travis is dash. I am facing difficulties in setting the shell to dash as its a non interactive environment. Could you please provide a way to set it to bash.

my .travis.yml

```
language: bash
os:
 - linux

sudo: required

install: sudo apt-get install -y gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib build-essential chrpath libsdl1.2-dev xterm git python expect
script:
 - sudo expect ./.change_dash_to_bash.sh;
 - sh ./.build_using_travis.sh
```

./.change_dash_to_bash.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn dpkg-reconfigure dash -freadline
expect "Use dash as the default system shell (/bin/sh)?"
send "N\r"

# done
expect eof
```

Project is https://github.com/johansaji/rpi_yocto

Comment: What about this attempt isn't working? Can you not just run `bash ./.build_using_travis.sh`? Or is that not enough?

Comment: @EtanReisner that won't work. Yocto expects the build machine to be bash.

Comment: Can you just run the `bash`-expecting script via `bash script`?

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь  bash-expecting script via bash script is working  in my local machine

Comment: Yocto expects `/bin/sh` to be `bash`? That's unfortunate.

Comment: @EtanReisner even ln is not working. invalid command name "ln"

Comment: That's not a `bash` vs. `sh` thing. That's something else entirely. What's the **exact** error message? Because that almost looks like a `tcl` error message.

Comment: sudo sh ./.change_dash_to_bash.sh;
Re linked
/bin/dash
The command "sudo sh ./.change_dash_to_bash.sh;" exited with 0.
0.01s$ sh ./.build_using_travis.sh
./.build_using_travis.sh: 19: [: missing ]
./.build_using_travis.sh: 31: meta-monkos/setup-raspberrypi-monkos-environment: Syntax error: "do" unexpected (expecting "done")
The command "sh ./.build_using_travis.sh" exited with 2.
Done. Your build exited with 1.